# Formatting changed unexpectedly when run from script

Tags: powershell

If I run this from the powershell command prompt:

```
 foreach ($ip in (resolve-dnsname -name multiple.example.com -Type A )) {
   test-netconnection -RemoteAddress $ip.IPaddress -Port 636 `
     | select remoteAddress,tcptestsucceeded
 }
```

I get a nice tabular output of IP addresses and test results:

```
RemoteAddress  TcpTestSucceeded
-------------  ----------------
10.3.2.1                   True 
10.3.2.2                   True
10.3.2.3                   True
...
```

But when I put this in a file and run it from Powershell, it returns a multi-line response for each value:

```
RemoteAddress     : 10.3.2.1
TCPTest Succeeded : True 

RemoteAddress     : 10.3.2.2
TCPTest Succeeded : True

RemoteAddress     : 10.3.2.3
TCPTest Succeeded : True
```

I tried appending `| format-table` both inside the loop (got multiple tables) and outside the loop (ErrorId EmptyPipeElement).

How do I get my script to format the output in a single table?

(Ideally I would get a timestamp for each line in the output too - but that's really a separate question)

Comment: [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Collect the results of your foreach loop in a variable by placing a `$Results =` in front of the foreach loop. Then you can pipe this variable to `Format-Table`.